# Meaning of this part of the Bitcoin Ticker Display?

Tags: ticker

When looking at the Bitcoin Ticker site: https://bitcointicker.co/stamp/btc/usd/1hr/

I see the part of the screen pictured below.  I'm having trouble understanding what this is presenting.  Can someone please help me understand it?

[image: Bitcoin Ticker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s the market depth and it’s not related to bitcoin, any exchange of any asset provides this information. One way to interpret it is if someone sent a big market sell order of 22.542 BTC to this exchange, the price would drop to $52554.